# Getting an error from jekyll-sitemap plugin: undefined method `fetch' for true:TrueClass in sitemap.xml

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler, jekyll-extensions

First question here and new to Ruby and Jekyll so forgive me if I miss some important details.

I'm trying to use `bundle exec jekyll serve` to generate my static site, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
  Liquid Exception: undefined method `fetch' for true:TrueClass in sitemap.xml
```

**Edit:** The problem was I had deleted/modified the something in my collections configuration in my _config.yml.

It should have been

```
collections:
  my_collection:
    output: true
```

...but instead was simply

```
collections:
      output: true
```

Not sure if it was always like that, or if I had modified it somehow. Check your _config.yml!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you have some code or logs to share? Have you tried `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace`? I have read the docs on https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap and haven't found any hint.

Comment: Hi Christian! Thanks for your reply. Editing my post with the results of `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace`

Comment: The error comes from [this line of the source code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/654d3810395f2247a699b3aa3f828bc6d1ef30f6/lib/jekyll/collection.rb#L187). I guess it is somehow related to your collection configuration or collection metadata in your config.yml file. 
A similar issue was [reported and fixed by changing the config here](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/1799) and I suggest to read more about [Jekyll collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the gem without getting any error.

_config.yml

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-sitemap

collections_dir: my_collections

collections:
  books:
    output: true
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' do 
  gem "jekyll"
  gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
end
```

book.md in my_collections\books

```
---
title: first book
---

first book
```

Resulting sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://localhost:4000/books/book/</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://localhost:4000/</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

As said in my comment above I assume that there is a problem in your collection configuration in your _config.yml file. Also, there are some known issues listed on the [official plugin page](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap).

Comment: This is it!!! I had somehow deleted a vital line in my collection configuration. Just replaced it and everything is running smoothly. Thank you so much.